# Assume G is a $r$-regular bigraph, $r \ge 1$. Show that a) G admits a $1$-factor

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Assume G is a $r$-regular bigraph, r$\ge$1.

Show that

a) G admits a 1-factor

b) the edge chromatic number of G is r;in other words, G can be decomposed into 1-factor.

I think I can use the Marriage theorem. Here is the definition:[image]

For part a), I would like to state that G has equal size of W and W', so we can produce a matching which covers the left part and the right part. Is this enought to show G admits a 1-factor?

Also, does a) and b) mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

(a). Let $G=(A\cup B, E)$. First note that $G$ being $r-$regular implies $|A|=|B|$. So it suffices to show $G$ admits a matching of $A$. Take any $S\subseteq A$, by $r-$regularity, we have $|\delta(S)| = |S|r$, which then implies $|N(S)|\ge |S|$. Then, by Hall's theorem, $G$ admits a matching of $A$.

(b). You can prove this by induction. Assume the statement is true for $(r-1)-$regular graphs. Then for a $r-$regular graph $G$, we know from the previous part that it admits a 1-factor, which we denote by $M$. Then $G-M$ is $(r-1)$-regular, which by inductive hypothesis can be decomposed into $(r-1)$ perfect matchings. Combining them with $M$ gives a decomposition of $G$.